# Is there a better way to avoid error when using ADODB.Command with parameters?

Tags: vba, ado

I had some existing VBA code that was building queries using string concatenation. I updated the code to use a command object with a parameter instead, but then started getting an error every once in a while that said `String data, right truncation`. After looking into it, I found out that if my collection of strings started with a string smaller than the rest, it would fail when it got to a longer string. To make it work, I just added some code to sort the collection from largest to smallest. Easy enough for this example since I know I won't have more than a few strings, but if I ever have a larger collection of strings, it might be an issue.

Is there any other way around this besides sorting the collection? Below is the section of code that causes the issue.

```
Dim lineNumbers As New Collection
Dim cnDb as new ADODB.Connection
Dim cmd as new ADODB.Command
Dim rs as new ADODB.RecordSet

lineNumbers.Add "001-3""-5116323-ABA"         
lineNumbers.Add "001-1""-5116327-ABA-1 1/2""C"  ' If not sorted, it fails when it tries this one
lineNumbers.Add "001-1""-5116327-ABA"
lineNumbers.Add "001-1""-5116327-ABA-1""C"

sQry = "SELECT COUNT(commondatalink) FROM commondata WHERE reportedlineno = ?"
cmd.ActiveConnection = cnDb
cmd.CommandText = sQry
cmd.CommandType = adCmdText

For i = 1 To lineNumbers.Count
    Set rs = cmd.Execute(, Array(lineNumbers(i))) ' Error thrown here on unsorted list
    If rs(0) > 1 Then
    ' do something...
    End If
Next i
```

Comment: Seems like you can't re-use a command object like that: first time it runs it may infer the parameter type/length, and if a subsdequent call uses a longer value that triggers the error. You could try explicitly creating the parameter using `cmd.CreateParameter()` and setting the size to the size of the field being queried (or a little larger)

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll try that tomorrow morning.

Comment: @TimWilliams That worked out well. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you can't re-use a command object like that: first time it runs it may infer the parameter type/length, and if a subsequent call uses a longer value that triggers the error.

You could try explicitly creating the parameter using cmd.CreateParameter() and setting the size to the size of the field being queried (or a little larger)